# Evenly distributed menu for complex order

Tags: html, css

I have HTML and CSS as follows:

```css
ul {
  display: inline;
  width: 300px;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li {
  display: inline;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li li {
  display: inline;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home
    <ul>
      <li>HR</li>
      <li>Finance</li>
      <li>Operations</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The ouptput result looks like:

 
Home      HR Finance Operations

I want to remove the space between Home and HR to create an evenly distributed menu items.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `ul` elements have a default `padding-left` value, which is set by the browser in the default user-agent stylsheet. You could set that to `0`:

```css
ul {
  display: inline;
  width: 300px;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
}
ul li {
  display: inline;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li li {
  display: inline;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home
    <ul>
      <li>HR</li>
      <li>Finance</li>
      <li>Operations</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I satisfied with your answer @josh-crozier the items are not evenly distributed along the menu

Answer (score 0):

You need to set UL as a `table` and `li` as table-cell..

Eg

```
ul{ display: table;}
li {display: table-cell;}
```

Comment: It's not working its not like a simple <li> items under <ul>. Please read question carefully